# How to output an image or icon for selected check box in a custom post

Tags: custom-post-types

I have created a custom post type for a property rental site created with WordPress. In it I want to have the input section as checkboxes:

[image: image one]

and get the output like this:

[image: image two]

Comment: use this plugin and enjoy its features, your answer is in the first page of its website. :) [Advanced Custom Fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com//])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by custom meta, all you have to do create custom metabox and the your checkboxes on it, the easiest way to create custom metabox is

> 1). Download WP Alchemy Metabox Class from [here](http://www.farinspace.com/wpalchemy-metabox/)
>
> 2). Palce 'wpalchemy' folder inside of your theme folder

in your function.php file

```
include_once WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/themes/yourtheme/wpalchemy/MetaBox.php';
```

> 3). after that, create two php files by following names 'my-special-feature-meta.php' , 'my-special-feature-spec.php' (you can name your php files whatever you want).

in your 'my-special-feature-spec.php' file

```
<?php
global my_special_features; 
$my_special_features = new WPAlchemy_MetaBox(array
(
    'id' => '_my_special_features',
    'title' => 'Special Features',
    'template' => get_stylesheet_directory() . 'my-special-feature-meta.php',
    'types' => array('page','post','your_custom_post')
));

/* eof */
```

and your 'my-special-feature-meta.php' file

Group checkbox test #1

```
<?php 
 global $my_special_features;
 $items = array('internet', 'laundry', 'garage', 'tv'); 
?>

    <?php while ($my_special_features->have_fields('cb_ex', count($items))): ?>

        <?php $item = $items[$mb->get_the_index()]; ?>

        <input type="checkbox" name="<?php $my_special_features ->the_name(); ?>" value="<?php echo $item; ?>"<?php $my_special_features ->the_checkbox_state($item); ?>/> <?php echo $item; ?><br/>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

okay you have created your checkbox lists in your custom post type, now you have to display the meta results on your front end, to do that, create php function in your functions.php file

```
function display_special_fetures(){
    global $my_special_features; 
    $myresults = $my_special_features->the_meta();
    if(!empty($myresults)){
     foreach($myresults){
        echo '<img src="'get_stylesheet_directory().'/'.$myresults['cb_ex'].'">';
      }
    }
}
```

finally place this function inside your loop or single.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-field-suite/

After that, in your template file, just use plugin's API:

```
<?php if( $cfs->get('field_name') ): ?>
<img src="blank.gif" class="sprite icon" />
<?php endif; ?>
```

Plugin Documentation: http://uproot.us/projects/cfs/documentation/

Of course, you can use Wordpress built-in functionality, just add your custom field on post edit screen, then use [get_post_meta()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta) to get custom field value.

Comment: First of all tnx,
Second Let me try this. :)

Comment: Still it is not clear for me, so let me ask again this way

I have the custom post type field check boxes named 
[]Internet
[]TV
[]Recreation